# How to check if explorer has a specific function loaded?

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I'm trying to find out a way to know If there are copy jobs in progress under the explorer process.

I already checked the function used by explorer to copy the file (CopyFileExW), so what I'd like to know is if there is any way to check if explorer has that function loaded to be sure that there is a copy in progress.

If I check the SHCORE thread stack I can see the function loaded (KERNELBASE.dll!CopyFileExW).

Anyone has some clue about how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone get Raymond Chen, we've got the makings of an Old New Thing blog post on our hands.

Comment: Not sure that the suggested duplicate will answer the question.

Comment: I am just curious, what is your use case?

Comment: Why is it important, specifically, to know if this is happening inside the explorer process and not anywhere else?

Comment: Hi. I'll need to restart the explorer.exe to refresh some settings, that is the reason why I need to check if there is any copy job in progress inside the explorer.

Comment: In that case, I agree with @ta.speot.is - if you think that restarting explorer is part of the solution to a problem you're dealing with, you've picked the *wrong* solution. And now, instead of presenting us with the *problem*, you're presenting us with the problem with *your* solution. What makes you think that a copy job is, necessarily, the only risky operation that can occur inside explorer that means you should avoid restarting it? Also, it's independent from your code - by the time you *know* whether a copy is occurring, that knowledge could be out of date.

Comment: Im not seeing another way to do what I need to do besides restart the explorer. Im not happy with that approach as well, but I really need to do it. In my point of view the copy job is the critical process here, but I could be wrong....Nevertheless I need to apply a group policy and remove it without restart the computer, so the restart explorer seems to be the only way to get it.

Comment: *In my point of view the copy job is the critical process here* In my opinion it's *a* critical job. Explorer does several. *I need to apply a group policy and remove it without restart the computer* What doesn't `gpupdate /force` do for you that you have to kill Explorer?

Comment: ta.speot.is the gpupdate /force only refresh settings but you need to logoff or restart the computer in some of them to get the settings applied. That is the case.I'm doing changes on start screen layout (Windows 8.1). So the gpupdate /force isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check if a Copy Operation is on, Hook CopyFileExW. This will let you know whenever a copy file is in progress.

Comment: Hi stamhaney. Do you have any example in C# to guide me? I'll probably launch my application when the copy job is already in progress. Do you know if there is any problem with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Does `explorer.exe` implement file copies exclusively with `CopyFileExW`? Which versions of Windows have an `explorer.exe` implement file copies exclusively with `CopyFileExW`? Make specific reference to the implementation details of unwritten versions of `explorer.exe` in future versions of Windows. If a file copy is paused, is `CopyFileExW` still present in the stack?

Comment: @user2964193 , I googled up some sample code. Here is the [link](http://groupes.codes-sources.com/article-hook-copie-fichier-262275.aspx) . I am not sure if this works, but it will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks stamhaney. I'll have a look on that.